# Calculating Flux through surface, stokes theorem, cant figure out parameterization of vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: !(https://www.dropbox.com/s/qrocdf3r4tb7sbg/Screenshot%202014-12-14%2011.56.28.png?dl=0)]

I am a tutor and trying to solve this for a student. I understand that Stokes's theorem allows us to compute the flux through the surface S, instead through the surface of the unit disk because they share the same boundary. Parameterize the disk as $\phi(r,\theta)=\left<r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, 0\right>$ with $0 \le r \le 1$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. My concern is that the solutions manual says:

> by what we know about the problem $\mathbf{F}(\phi(r,\theta)) = \left<0,0,1\right>$

without any further information as to how it was obtained. Now I come to you much smarter folk than I, how in the world was that computed? Is there some properties of the curl of a vector field I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like utter garbage to me. :) Just apply Stokes's Theorem directly. To say $\mathbf A$ is a vector potential for $\mathbf F$ is to say that $\mathbf F = \operatorname{curl} \mathbf A$, so
$$\int_S \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS = \int_S \operatorname{curl} \mathbf A\cdot\mathbf n\,dS = \int_{\partial S}\mathbf A\cdot d\mathbf r = 25.$$

Comment: Could very well be.  Keep in mind solutions manuals are usually not written by the textbook's authors.

Comment: Agreed, @MatthewLeingang, although I did my own to avoid such nonsense, and I too made the occasional errors :)

Comment: Author to author, I salute you! :-D

Comment: Yes thank you I felt like I was taking crazy pills. My initial reaction to reading the problem was just to apply stokes directly and get 25. Then I had students telling me that answer was wrong. Looked it up in the solutions manual and they have 2pi as the solution. Frustrating for students who have to submit answers to an online grading software. So they have to put in a wrong answer, event though 25 is correct.

Comment: @user130771: That is horrendous. They (or you) need to contact the instructor and alert them that there's a serious error. This happens to us from time to time with on-line homeworks. I immediately fix the coding when it's ones I've written :P ... Most likely, that's the answer to another question. Either something changed from one edition to another or someone just plain screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

Since flux through a closed surface is equal to zero 
(Flux through S) +(Flux through unit disk)=0
Therefore we get:
(Flux through S) = - (Flux through unit disk)